# How to make Xcode 8.2.1 refresh provisioning profile list ? seems like Xcode bug

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, xcode8.2

new provisioning profile appears in Apple's dev portal, but I can't see it in Xcode, tried to Download all profiles, kill Xcode, restart computer, none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen similar issues and I think its an XCode bug also, try the following:

1. Open your provisioning profiles folder(right click on any existing one and show in Finder).
2. Make a back up of existing profiles just in case(select all, compress, etc)
3. Delete those profiles
4. Download all again from XCode and it should work.

Comment: @Bhimbim try here: `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`